# Reading m words from a paragraph from n thread ? C++ multithreading ? Not working?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, mutex, deadlock

I want read a paragraph by extracting one word at a time using Multithreading . Each thread should read exactly one word and when paragraph ends they should exit peacefully . I know threads shouldn't be used in this way as there is no advantage in that . But I want to do that so that I can check how threads can work sequentially if required . I tried but it looks like the program is reaching deadlock state and not giving any output at all . There are 11 words in the string and I am using 4 threads .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <sstream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
using namespace std;
stringstream s("Japan US Canada UK France Germany China Russia Korea India Nepal");
int count = 0;
string word;
condition_variable cv;
mutex m;
int i = 0;
bool check_func(int i,int k)
{
    return i == k;
}
void print(int k)
{
  while(count < 11)   // As there are 11 words
  {
     unique_lock<mutex> lk(m);
     int z = k;
     cv.wait(lk,[&]{return check_func(i,z);});            // Line 33
     s >> word;
     cout<<word<<" ";
     i++;
     cv.notify_all();
     count++;
  }
   return;
}
int main() 
{
    thread threads[4];
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
       threads[i] = thread(print,i);
    for(auto &t : threads)
       t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this code:

```
while(count < 11)   // As there are 11 words
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lk(m);
    int z = k;
    cv.wait(lk,[&]{return check_func(i,z);});            // Line 33
    s >> word;
    cout<<word<<" ";
    i++;
    cv.notify_all();
    count++;
}
```

To this:

```
int z = k;
while(z < 11)   // As there are 11 words
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lk(m);
    int z = k;
    cv.wait(lk,[&]{return check_func(i,z);});            // Line 33
    s >> word;
    cout<<word<<" ";
    i++;
    z+=4;
    cv.notify_all();
    count++;
}
```

Three things changed in the above: the declaration of z is moved outside of the loop, the condition in the `while` changed to check `z` instead of `count`, and the line `z+=4` added. You need to increment z by 4 each time if you want each of your threads to move onto the next word. Also, you need to check z not count because otherwise some of the threads will overshoot and the last word will be printed multiple times (consider the thread that reads the ninth word: if checking on count instead of z it continues on to the next iteration of the loop even though there will be nothing further for it to read).

Comment: Well , may be I didn't explain the code in right manner . But implementing your  suggestion which is commenting notify and wait will lead to reading all the words by the first thread while rest three will read the last word again and again printing the string + Nepal 4 times , which should have been only once . The target was each thread should read one word at a time in a round robin manner and once the string is completely read exit peacefully . Second thing , the global variable i is getting changed  . Just see after  s >> word;   you will see i++ ; I guess you miss that . Anyway thanks !

Comment: Yes you're right, I did miss that. But consider this: your `cv.wait(...)` waits for a condition that can only possibly be true for one iteration of the `while` loop for each thread (because z never changes but i does). So none of your threads could possibly complete the loop more than once. Anyway, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Well z+= 4 is not working either and the program is getting hanged reason every thread will definitely  every thread will initialize z with  its parameter vale but each thread will increment it with 4 as well which make the predicate becomes falls in the very second execution of the loop . The appropriate correction is  if( i == 4 ) i = 0; this will make the required result possible and yes one more s >> word to if(s >> word) hope you know the reason why . And yes all the condition variables wait function and notify are a must , without that the program won't work in any manner .

Comment: Did you put in the other changes as well (not just adding z+=4)? I tried this code and it works as you want it to.

Comment: Boss I copied your entire code and its not working putting * infintee number of times until program hanged . Reason is same which I mentioned above .

Comment: The program works for me. Your reasoning is not correct either - you say the predicate becomes false forever on the second iteration of the loop for every thread, but this is not the case. Consider what happens to thread0 after 1 iteration: its z-value is 4 and it has just incremented i to 1. After thread1, thread2, and thread3 go, each of those will have incremented i by 1 so i will be 4 when thread3 is just about to finish its first iteration. Thus when thread3 calls `cv.notify_all()` for the first time thread0 will wake up and its predicate will succeed. Same for other threads.

Comment: The other thing I can think of is that you should change `int i =0` to `std::atomic<int> i(0)` (you will need `#include <atomic>`. This should ensure all threads see updates to i properly in case this is what's causing the problem in your case